# c++11 includes <cstdlib> at times when c++03 will not?

Tags: c++, namespaces, c++11, g++

Take a look at this tiny program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

  int var = atoi("-99");      //convert string to int
  var = abs(var);             //takes absolute value
  std::cout << var+1 <<'\n';  //outputs 100

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

---

Compiling creates the following errors messages:

```
$ g++ -o main main.cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:5:13: error: ‘atoi’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:6:16: error: ‘abs’ was not declared in this scope
main.cpp:9:10: error: ‘EXIT_SUCCESS’ was not declared in this scope
```

Understandable. All of these exist in the "cstdlib" header which I neglected to include.
However, compiling with:

```
$ g++ -std=c++0x -o main main.cpp
```

creates no issues.

---

looking at the source of the "cstdlib" header, I see the following code at the bottom:

```
#ifdef __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
#  if defined(_GLIBCXX_INCLUDE_AS_TR1)
#    error C++0x header cannot be included from TR1 header
#  endif
#  if defined(_GLIBCXX_INCLUDE_AS_CXX0X)
#    include <tr1_impl/cstdlib>
#  else
#    define _GLIBCXX_INCLUDE_AS_CXX0X
#    define _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_TR1
#    define _GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE_TR1
#    define _GLIBCXX_TR1
#    include <tr1_impl/cstdlib>
#    undef _GLIBCXX_TR1
#    undef _GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE_TR1
#    undef _GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_TR1
#    undef _GLIBCXX_INCLUDE_AS_CXX0X
#  endif
#endif
```

I'm not sure if that is relevant or not.. full header file code [here](http://pastebin.com/2WrmiaUB)

my ultimate question is, does the new standard guarantee that all of cstdlib will be brought in at a global namespace when you include iostream?

I can't find any documentation on the matter.  Appears that way to me, does it appear that way to you?

```
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1
```

Comment: Btw, this title was totally misleading. C++11 **is** C++. It's not a new separate language.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> my ultimate question is, does the new standard guarantee that all of cstdlib will be brought in at a global namespace when you include iostream?

No. You should `#include` it yourself if you need its functionality. If you get it "for free" with `<iostream>`, that's a sign that your `<iostream>` header requires it, but then you're relying on an implementation detail of your C++ library.

Btw., `#include <cstdlib>` is not guaranteed to bring C functions into the global namespace (although it commonly does so in C++ implementations); it is guaranteed to put them in the namespace `std`:

> Except as noted in Clauses 18 through 30 and Annex D, the contents of each header `cname` shall be the same as that of the corresponding header `name.h`, as specified in the C standard library (1.2) or the C Unicode TR, as appropriate, as if by inclusion. In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace `std`. It is unspecified whether these names are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace `std` by explicit `using`-declarations (7.3.3).

(Standard, section 17.6.1.2)

Comment: thats strange, I didn't have to scope atoi

Comment: @Xploit: never mind my previous comment. `<cstdlib>` does put `atoi` in the namespace `std`; if yours puts it in the global namespace as well, then that's a platform-specific extension.

Comment: @larsmars That's not a feature, it's a bug. It's an unintended pollution of the global namespace - which is notoriously hard to avoid as library writer. gcc does a good job of slowly fleshing out those pollutions. BTW, thats one major source of miscompilation of software packets with newer version of gcc, which until then compiled fine.

Comment: I've just tried with Visual Studio 2010 and I have the exact same behaviour ... no need to specify std namespace.

Comment: @Uflex: then MSVC has the same bug.

Comment: @larsmans It's not a bug, as the new C++ standard allows this behavior. The `<cfoo>` version of C headers put everything in `std::` and might put them in the global namespace as well. The `<foo.h>` headers put everything in the global namespace and might put them in the `std::` namespace as well. Sorry, can't find a link at the moment.

Comment: Link found! See comments at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/5079548/396551 and the official entry 456 at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#456

Comment: @Sjoerd: I checked the standard text again and it seems this is indeed allowed. Still, the OP should not rely on `::atoi` being declared in `<cstdlib>`.

Comment: @larsmans Agree on that. I had upvoted your answer already, as I consider this a minor point. Your first comment that it is a *platform-specific extension* was correct; I should have directed my comments at drhirsch, who called it a bug.